# remove white line with multicol in longtable

Tags: longtable, multicol

I've got in a longtable with one column split into two by multicol. Somehow multicol adds a white line before starting with the text.
[image: example of white line]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\begin{longtable}{|l|X|}
1 & \begin{multicols}{2}1. text \newline 2. text \newline 3. text \newline 4. text \newline 5. text \newline 6. text  \end{multicols} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your mwe is not working and I'm not sure how to complete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your MWE is missing several critical packages and commands, I tried the following fix so it works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,ltxtable,filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{longtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|l|X|}
1 & \begin{multicols}{2}
1. text \newline 
2. text \newline 
3. text \newline 
4. text \newline 
5. text \newline 
6. text  
\end{multicols}
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

Then, to fix your problem, simply add:

```
\setlength\multicolsep{-\baselineskip}
```

to your preamble. Check the result:
[image]

For more detail about spacing, check the package document.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the white line **above** the text, I was annoyed by the white line **under** the text. My question didn't include this one, but the solution for this extra problem is by adding `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after `\end{multicols}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,ltxtable,filecontents}
\setlength\multicolsep{-\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{longtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|l|X|}
\hline
1 &
\begin{multicols}{2}
1. text \newline 2. text \newline 3. text \newline 4. text \newline 5. text \newline 6. text
\end{multicols} \vspace{-\baselineskip}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this now:
[image: solution]